# PHP warning include(DateInterval.php) issue

Tags: php, yii

Hi I just move my my project from local to server and it start showing me an error message

```
PHP warning

include(DateInterval.php) [<a href='function.include'>function.include</a>]: failed to open stream: No such file or directory
```

Any idea why is showing this error .... it's working fine locally

Comment: check the `include_path` ~ almost certainly the default on the live server will be different to that which you used on your dev server

Comment: also you could check the file name case

Comment: @RamRaider @seravee i haven't added this `include(DateInterval.php)` line of code ...may be framwork do.:(

Comment: on both systems( live and dev), on some page or other, try `echo get_include_path();` and compare

Comment: @RamRaider it showing `locally = .;F:\wamp\www\site_name\protected\components;F:\wamp\www\site_name\protected\models;C:\php\pear
server = .:/home/d27986/public_html/new/protected/components:/home/d27986/public_html/new/protected/models:/opt/alt/php52/usr/share/pear:/opt/alt/php52/usr/share/php`